# Is poultry suitable for dry aging like beef is?

Tags: chicken, poultry

In "The Science of Good Cooking" it is said that the reason why a roast at a restaurant tastes so well is because they age their meat for days. Enzymes break down the protein (not collagen) and make the muscles more tender.

I wonder if that same process is applicable to poultry. Is there a point to dry aging (or cooking on a very low temp for long time. Not slow cooking) a chicken roast or a chicken breast?

Comment: 'cooking on a very low temp for a long time' has nothing to do with dry-ageing, and is the exact definition of 'slow-cooking' so I would remove this from your question (and look up sous-vide chicken recipes if you want to know more)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting health and safety concerns aside, there are a few reasons why dry-ageing chicken or other poultry is unheard of (or at least very rare):

- Poultry is usually tender meat by nature
- Poultry easily dries out when roasting/pan frying/baking. Dry ageing would mean the meat starts off drier to begin with
- The flavour profile of aged beef is more gamey and overall stronger. This would generally not be considered a desirable taste in chicken

There are white meats that do often undergo an ageing process (pheasant, partridge etc.), but this is done before plucking and gutting, meaning the meat does not lose as much moisture, and there is less risk of introducing infection.

Comment: What about the turkey jerky you can buy readily (here in the UK)? Also you can buy fish jerky too (never tried it) but that isn't related to the question :)

Comment: Jerky is 'dried', not 'dry-aged' (and it is most likely cooked as well in the case of turkey jerky). Foods that are dried are often intended to be eaten raw straight away, dry-ageing involves storing meat until it is ready to be cooked - once the flavour has developed and meat has tenderised

Answer (score 3):

We pasture-raise heritage chicken (meat birds).

We have a commercial refrigeration unit and regularly dry age chickens for 7 to 10 days at 35 degrees. They are spectacular eating.[image: Aged Chicken]